# Animating Text Field Expanding Like Messenger & Whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm attempting to have my message textfield expand when a user begins typing by animating the Right layout constraint. The textfield does expand however it expands both ways from the center which is not the desired effect, since I am only updating one constraint why is the other changing?

```
func animateTextField(textfield : UITextField, constraint : NSLayoutConstraint) {
    let isTextFieldExpanded = constraint.constant == 15
    constraint.constant = isTextFieldExpanded ? 59 : 15
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        textfield.layoutIfNeeded()
        textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    })
}
```

For more context, I call the method in the same View model, which I then call from my view controller.

```
func handleTypingAnimation(view : UIView, textField : UITextField, constraint : NSLayoutConstraint) {

    if textField.text?.isEmpty == false {
        animateSendButtonAppear(view: view)
        animateTextField(view: view, textfield: textField, constraint: constraint)
    }else{
        animateSendButtonHide(view: view)
    }
}
```

My View Controller

```
@IBAction func didStartTyping(_ sender: UITextField) {
    messageVM.handleTypingAnimation(view: sendButtonView, textField: messageTextField, constraint: textfieldRightConstraint)
}
```

My Layout Constraint

```
@IBOutlet var textfieldRightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  //  textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

You should always re-layout the parent when you make a change in a child's constraints

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't have any effect. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: show all constraints of that textfield and how && where you call this

Comment: Apologies, I posted the comment before you updated your answer, I changed it from textfield.layoutifneeded() to view.layoutifneeded() and it fixed the constraint issue, but now it does not animate.

Comment: do you think 0.2 seconds is a long value ??

Comment: The transition was clear when using 0.2 when using textfield.layoutifneeded(), but now even using 4 seconds, the animation simply does not work, it simply just moves the constraint.

Comment: where you call it pls provide full context

Comment: i think the problem because of you have 2 animations below each others , can you comment the other and try

Comment: I just removed the function and tryed just with animateTextField and there was no change, it seems that calling textfield.layoutifneeded() shows the constraints animating but with the weird expand behaviour, and view.layoutifneeded() fixes the weird expand behaviour but calls no animation

Comment: How you create the constraint you pass in **handleTypingAnimation** ?? , show all cons of the textfeild , do you see any conflicts in console ??

Comment: also in which event of the textfeild you add the selector **didStartTyping** , it seems it's called many times

Comment: The constraint is manually created in storyboard, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: didStartTyping is an Outlet created in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I realised I was using the wrong view: View input in the func, I removed handleTyping and added func animateTextField into DidStartTyping by itself and then used the correct view, the animation and the constraints work perfectly, thanks!